# Parsing Table with Jsoup for Android App

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am attempting to parse through a table on a website for a give table row in which the first column matches a certain string of characters. Below is the HTML for part of the table (it's very larger)

```
<table class="table display datatable" id="datatable1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="va-m">Miner</th>
            <th class="va-m">Shares</th>
            <th class="va-m">%</th>
            <th class="va-m">Best DL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th class="va-m">Miner</th>
            <th class="va-m">Shares</th>
            <th class="va-m">%</th>
            <th class="va-m">Best DL</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>3R8RDBxiux3g1pFCCsQnm2vwD34axsVRTrEWzyX8tngJaRnNWkbnuFEewzuBAKhQrb3LxEQHtuBg1zW4tybt83SS</td>
            <td>44279</td>
            <td>27.37 %</td>
            <td>1154</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5gwVxC9cXguHHjD9wtTpHfsJPaZx4fPcvWD5jGWF1dcuHnAMyXxteaHrEtXviZkvWN3FAnevbVLErABSsP6mS7PR</td>
            <td>36369</td>
            <td>22.48 %</td>
            <td>2725</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2qZXPmop82UiA7LQEQqdoUzjFbcwCSpqf8U1f3656XXSsHnGvGXYTNoP11s2asiVSyVS8LPFqxmpdCeSNxcpFMnF</td>
            <td>28596</td>
            <td>17.68 %</td>
            <td>967</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21mbNSDo7g9BAyjsZGxnNfJUrEtBUVVNQZhR4tkVwdEHPaMNsa2u2JHQPAAe5riGfPA9Khb1Pq3bQGhqmrLEGNqN</td>
            <td>6104</td>
            <td>3.77 %</td>
            <td>4787</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4HAakKK7dSq18Djg7m6cLSyHb5aUU6ngvBQimo8pYyF5F64qX3gE4T8q8kfWHTZ79FvXybSG3JhUfSZDDv2sRwqY</td>
            <td>5895</td>
            <td>3.64 %</td>
            <td>6020</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2r2izPEC5o7ZDnUsdDA97q8wKCeZRRg9n243Rd9vkMQqRCtc6ZRUTruQUyZGduoHy8pTYPuEq9ACXPKfXt8fqKxS</td>
            <td>5605</td>
            <td>3.46 %</td>
            <td>10958</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to step through the table and search for a specific row but I am receiving an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Would there be a better way to code the statement below?

```
for (Element table : doc.select("table")){
    for(Element row : table.select("tr")){
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
        if(tds.get(0).text().equals("4HjSN79KUMz7AQC3GBvGkgPa5Qrio9HWTh7hg9JY48fkrYeVZJVmzB9YCB6GZSpuXB7V7DjJVuke3ZaCm5k7sRLE")){
            myHistoricShares =tds.get(0).text();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you're selecting a `<tr>` which contains no `<td>` elements, only `<th>`. So `row.select("td")` gives you an empty list, and `tds.get(0)`  throws the exception

Answer (score 2):

As I said in comments, your `table.select("tr")` selects rows not only inside `<tbody>`, but inside the header and the footer too. For those rows `row.select("td")` returns an empty list, and hence `tds.get(0)` throws the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You could simplify your loop by selecting only the rows in `<tbody>`:

```
for (Element row: doc.select("table#datatable1>tbody>tr")) {
    if (row.children().size() > 0 && "some_long_string".equals(row.child(0).text())) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

The selector `"table#datatable1>tbody>tr"` selects the table with `id="datatable1"`, then its exact `tbody` child and then all its exact `tr` children. So you only need to iterate through them once.